# Actioncable timeout disconnect not triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma, actioncable

on Actioncable, when i disable my wifi to simulate an internet lost, the `unsubscribed` method in Channel or the `disconnect` methods in Connection didn't triggered. How to active the timeout disconnection ?

Here it's my config of actioncable with rails / capistrano / puma / nginx :

Rails `5.0.0.1` side :

```
# config/cable.yml
staging:
    adapter: redis
    url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

and

```
# cable/config.ru
require ::File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
Rails.application.eager_load!

run ActionCable.server
```

and with capistrano/puma

```
set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'cable/config.ru') }
```

Nginx side:

```
upstream app {
  server unix:/home/ubuntu/rails-app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name ws.domain.co;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co/privkey.pem;

  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
    proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this issue as well and it seems disconnect does trigger. Just not in a few seconds like it should according to documentation, but in a few minutes.

You can `'watch -n 1 'netstat -na | grep YourPort'` to see that connection actually is still there so the disconnect callback shouldn't be triggered.

I've opened an issue on github regarding this problem.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27082